# call to FundMe.getVersion errored: VM execution error. Reverted 0x

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  >=0.6.0 <0.9.0 ;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  function description() external view returns (string memory);

  function version() external view returns (uint256);

  // getRoundData and latestRoundData should both raise "No data present"
  // if they do not have data to report, instead of returning unset values
  // which could be misinterpreted as actual reported values.
  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );
}

contract FundMe {
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public addressTotalAmountFunded;
        
    
    function fund() public payable {
        addressTotalAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    
    
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
        return priceFeed.version();
        
   }        
}
```

Hi I am trying to understand why I get this error when I want to check the version
Any thoughts?

Comment: On which network are you deploying the contract and executing the `getVersion()`? Remix VM emulator, Ethereum Ropsten testnet, Ethereum mainnet, BSC mainnet, ...

Comment: Remix VM on Kovan Network

Answer (score 1):

The `0x5f4e...` address hardcoded in your `getVersion()` function doesn't hold any smart contract on the Kovan testnet ([link](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419)). Even though it has a contract deployed on the mainnet, these environments are separated.

When there's no smart contract on the address, there's nothing to send a response to the internal call. Your code expects an `uint256` response from the `version()` call, so that it can return it from the `getVersion()`.

When it doesn't receive the expected response, it throws an exception, effectively reverting the "main" call.

---

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the address of the data feed is for the Testnet you are using (most likely Kovan) and not for Mainnet.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. The problem was with the network selection. You're requesting the price info from a wallet address/contract on Rinkby network. I tried the wallet address on the Kovan network instead and that worked for me.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the Kovan address I used 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
It worked find a returned the ETH/USD Price info.

So basically you can solve it in 2 ways:

1. Go to your metamask and change your network to Rinkby and use the rinkby ETH/USD address in your functions or
2. Keep your network on Kovan and use the Kovan ETH/USD address.